# difference between biotic and living?

Tags: biochemistry

how  can we differentiate between *biotic* and *living* things,is  there any difference? and same for abiotic and non-living?
I think it is that biotic is like biomass and living should carry out life processes.

Comment: Have you tried googling dictionary definition of biotic/abiotic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **biotic**: relating to or resulting from living things, especially in their ecological relations (Oxford)

While there may be a field-specific connotation that I'm not aware of, I've never heard "biotic" as a category of "things" before. I am most familiar with it's use in the context of ecology, e.g. a parasite might be a biotic factor in the survival of a population of animals in a particular ecosystem.

To get to the heart of your question, I don't think there is a difference, but rather a relation: biotic factors *refer to* currently or formerly living things (and abiotic refers to things that are or were not alive).

Comment: But don't you think that a dead animalis non-living but still biotic facor.

Comment: Fair point, I edited my answer to make it hopefully clearer. The main point is that "biotic" and "living" are not two categories to compare; but that "biotic" refers to factors relating to or originating from "living things".